# Specialized layout with CSS Grid/Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm hoping I can get some tips on achieving a certain image gallery layout I've been trying to recreate, here is the layout: 
[image]

Link to the site https://www.styleshout.com/templates/preview/Sublime10/index.html

as you can see one image on each row is a bit higher than the other, and the other rows fit perfectly into each other.

Here is a measly codepen attempt I've made but I'm just completely stuck on how to get this layout:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  border-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.gallery-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 600px;
    

    figure {
      height: 350px;
      picture img {
        width: 350px;
        height: 350px;
      }
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Flexible Image Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gallery-container">
      <figure>
        <picture>
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/204x200" alt="" />
        </picture>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <picture>
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/209x200" alt="" />
        </picture>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <picture>
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/205x200" alt="" />
        </picture>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <picture>
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/202x200" alt="" />
        </picture>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <picture>
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/201x200" alt="" />
        </picture>
      </figure>
      <figure>
        <picture>
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/206x200" alt="" />
        </picture>
      </figure>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

- https://codepen.io/DMI801/pen/ZVQryQ

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To achieve the layout, you would need to use `flex-direction: column;` which wraps, and your photos must have same widths. Note however, that the example you had uses a library called [AOS - Animate On Scroll](https://github.com/michalsnik/aos)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution using flex:

- Create 2 divs with class `.column` to make 3 images in a column
- Add class `.grow` with `flex: 1.2` to make it 1.2 times higher than
  the others
- Set image `flex: 1` to make its height grow in container

Take a look at my demo:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    border-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

figure {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
figure > img {
    flex: 1;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    height: 800px;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.grow {
    flex: 1.2;
}

.gallery-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="gallery-container">
        <div class="column">
            <figure>
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/204x200" alt="" />
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/209x200" alt="" />
            </figure>
            <figure class="grow">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/205x200" alt="" />
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <figure class="grow">
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/202x200" alt="" />
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/201x200" alt="" />
            </figure>
            <figure>
                <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/206x200" alt="" />
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps to solve your problem.